# Check bounds changes variables

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I'm porting a program that I use in a chemistry classroom from Matlab (very forgiving) to Fortran (err, not so much). The problem I see is that if I include print statements in 1 subroutine, my code returns significantly different values than if I don't (the ones with the print statement included are correct).

After reading stack overflow, I removed the print statement, recompiled with gfortran and `fcheck='bounds'`, and my program returned the correct results, and no errors during compile.

The subroutines stored in a module `Basis_Subs`, and called from the main program, which I've posted below.  The problem appears in the 4 dimensional matrix `Gabcd(nb,nb,nb,nb)` which is constructed using the subroutine `Build_Electron_Repulsion` from the `Basis_Subs module`.  That subroutine calculates the matrix elements of `Gabcd`, and uses 1 internal helper functions,  `Rntuv`, and 1 internal subroutine `Gprod_1D`, both of which are also stored in the `Basis_Subs` module.

These functions/routines are used in another section of the program, and that portion of the program doesn't show any errors or funny array behavior. That leads me to think the problem must either be in `Build_Electron_Repulsion`, how I'm calling `Build_Electron_Repulsion` or how I'm calling the the helper functions from inside `Build_Electron_Repulsion`.

I've posted the main program, and the subroutines for `Build_Electron_Repulsion`, `gprod_1D`, and the function `Rntuv`.  What I'm really wondering is if you have any tips on tracking down where the error might be.

I'm using a pico style editor and gfortran.

Main Program, Z.f08

```
program HF
use typedefs
use Basis_Subs
use SCF_Mod
implicit none
real(dp) :: output, start, finish
integer (kind=4) :: IFLAG , i, N, nb,j,k,l,natom
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: Z
real(dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: AL, S,T, VAB, H0
real(dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:,:,:) :: Gabcd
real(dp), dimension(maxl) :: Ex=0
real(dp) :: Energy, Nuc
type(primitive) :: g1, Build_Primitive
type(Basis) :: b1
type(Basis), dimension(100) :: bases
character(LEN=20) :: fname
print *, 'Input the filename'
  read (*,*), fname
  open(unit=12, file=fname)
  read(12,*) natom
  allocate(Z(natom))
  allocate(AL(natom,3))
  read(12,*) Z
  do i=1, natom
    read(12,*) AL(i,1), AL(i,2), AL(i,3)
  end do

print *, 'Atomic Coorinates = ', AL
print *, 'Z in the main routine = ', Z
call cpu_time(start)

%Calculate the energies that don't depend on electrons
call Nuclear_Repulsion(natom, Z, AL, Nuc)
N=Sum(Z)

%Build the atom specific basis set
call Build_Bases(Z, AL, nb, bases)

%Using nb, from Build_Basis, allocate matrices
allocate(S(nb,nb))
allocate(T(nb,nb))
allocate(VAB(nb,nb))
allocate(Gabcd(nb,nb,nb,nb))
call Build_Overlap(bases, nb, S)

call Build_Kinetic(bases, nb, T)

call Build_Nuclear_Attraction(Z, AL, bases, nb, VAB)
H0 = T+VAB

call Build_Electron_Repulsion(bases, nb, Gabcd)

call cpu_time(finish)
print *, 'Total time for Matrix Elements= ', finish - start

call SCF(N, nb, H0, S, Gabcd, Nuc, Energy)
end program HF
```

Build_Electron_Repulsion is located inside the module Basis_Subs:

```
       subroutine Build_Electron_Repulsion(bases, nbases, Gabcd)
!!Calculate the 4 centered electron repulsion integrals.  Loop over array of !!basis sets 1:nb  4 times.  Each element of basis set is a defined type that !!includes and  array of gaussian functions and contraction coefficients !!basis(a)%g(1:nga) and basis(a)%c(1:nga).  For each gaussian in each basis set, 
!!Calculate int(int(basis(a1)*basis(b1)*basis(c2)*basis(d2)*1/r12 dr1)dr2).  
!!Uses helper function Rntuv listed below
        implicit none
    type(basis), dimension(100), intent(in) :: bases
    integer, intent(in) :: nbases
    real(dp), dimension(nbases, nbases,nbases,nbases), intent(out) :: Gabcd
    integer :: a, b,c,d, nga, ngb, ngc, ngd, index, lx, ly, lz, llx, lly,llz
    integer :: llxmax, llymax, llzmax, lxmax, lymax, lzmax, xmax, ymax, zmax
    integer :: x, y, z
    real(dp) :: p, q, midpoint, PX, PY, PZ, output
    real(dp) :: pp, qq, midpoint2, PPX, PPY, PPZ, tmp
    real(dp) :: alpha_a, alpha_b, alpha_c, alpha_d, alpha
    real(dp) :: ax, ay, az, bx, by, bz, cx,cy,cz, dx,dy,dz
    real(dp), dimension(maxl) ::EabX, EabY, EabZ, EcdX, EcdY, EcdZ
    real(dp), dimension(2*maxl, 2*maxl, 2*maxl) :: R
    R=0
    Gabcd=0.0D0
        print *, 'Calculating 4 centered integrals'
    do a=1, nbases
    do b=1, nbases
    do c=1, nbases
    do d=1, nbases

        do nga = 1, bases(a)%n
        do ngb = 1, bases(b)%n
                alpha_a=bases(a)%g(nga)%alpha
                alpha_b=bases(b)%g(ngb)%alpha
                p=alpha_a + alpha_b
                ax=bases(a)%g(nga)%x
                ay=bases(a)%g(nga)%y
                az=bases(a)%g(nga)%z
                bx=bases(b)%g(ngb)%x
                by=bases(b)%g(ngb)%y
                bz=bases(b)%g(ngb)%z

                PX=(alpha_a*ax + alpha_b*bx)/p
                PY=(alpha_a*ay + alpha_b*by)/p
                PZ=(alpha_a*az + alpha_b*bz)/p

                call gprod_1D(ax, alpha_a, bases(a)%g(nga)%lx, bx, alpha_b,  bases(b)%g(ngb)%lx, EabX)
                call gprod_1D(ay, alpha_a, bases(a)%g(nga)%ly, by, alpha_b, bases(b)%g(ngb)%ly, EabY)
                call gprod_1D(az, alpha_a, bases(a)%g(nga)%lz, bz, alpha_b, bases(b)%g(ngb)%lz, EabZ)

                lxmax=bases(a)%g(nga)%lx + bases(b)%g(ngb)%lx
                lymax=bases(a)%g(nga)%ly + bases(b)%g(ngb)%ly
                lzmax=bases(a)%g(nga)%lz + bases(b)%g(ngb)%lz
        do ngc= 1, bases(c)%n
        do ngd = 1, bases(d)%n
                 alpha_c=bases(c)%g(ngc)%alpha
                alpha_d=bases(d)%g(ngd)%alpha
                pp=alpha_c + alpha_d
                cx=bases(c)%g(ngc)%x
                cy=bases(c)%g(ngc)%y
                cz=bases(c)%g(ngc)%z
                dx=bases(d)%g(ngd)%x
                dx=bases(d)%g(ngd)%y
                dz=bases(d)%g(ngd)%z

     PPX=(alpha_c*cx + alpha_d*dx)/pp
                PPY=(alpha_c*cy + alpha_d*dy)/pp
                PPZ=(alpha_c*cz + alpha_d*dz)/pp
                llxmax=bases(c)%g(ngc)%lx + bases(d)%g(ngd)%lx
                llymax=bases(c)%g(ngc)%ly + bases(d)%g(ngd)%ly
                llzmax=bases(c)%g(ngc)%lz + bases(d)%g(ngd)%lz

                call gprod_1D(cx, alpha_c, bases(c)%g(ngc)%lx, dx, alpha_d, bases(d)%g(ngd)%lx, EcdX)
                call gprod_1D(cy, alpha_c, bases(c)%g(ngc)%ly, dy, alpha_d, bases(d)%g(ngd)%ly, EcdY)
                call gprod_1D(cz, alpha_c, bases(c)%g(ngc)%lz, dz, alpha_d, bases(d)%g(ngd)%lz, EcdZ)

                alpha=p*pp/(p+pp)
                tmp=0
                xmax= lxmax + llxmax
                ymax = lymax + llymax
                zmax = lzmax + llzmax


                do x = 0, xmax
                        do y =0, ymax
                                do z=0,  zmax
                                                    R(x+1,y+1,z+1)=Rntuv(0,x,y,z,alpha, PX, PY, PZ, PPX, PPY, PPZ)
                                end do

                        end do
 end do
                !if (a ==1 .and. b==1 .and. c ==1 .and. d==1) then
                !       print *,' R = ', R(1,1,1)
                !print *, xmax, ymax, zmax
                !print *,a,b,c,d,nga,ngb,ngc,ngd, 'R = ', R(1,1,1)
                !end if
        !       if (PZ ==PPZ) then
        !       !       print *, R(1,1,1)
        !               output = Rntuv(0,0,0,0,alpha, PX, PY, PZ, PPX, PPY, PPZ)
        !               print *, output
      !                 print *, a,b,c,d , PY, PPY
                !
        !       end if
                do lx = 0, lxmax
                do ly = 0, lymax
                do lz = 0, lzmax
                do llx= 0, llxmax
                do lly= 0, llymax
                do llz= 0, llzmax
                        tmp = tmp + EabX(lx+1)*EabY(ly+1)*EabZ(lz+1)*(-1.0D0)**(llx + lly + llz) * &
                                EcdX(llx+1)*EcdY(lly+1)*EcdZ(llz+1)*R(lx+ llx+1, ly+lly+1, lz+llz+1)

                end do
                end do
                end do
                end do
 end do
                end do
                Gabcd(a,b,c,d) = Gabcd(a,b,c,d) + 2.0D0*pi**2.5D0/(p*pp*sqrt(p + pp))*tmp*bases(a)%g(nga)%N &
                * bases(b)%g(ngb)%N * bases(c)%g(ngc)%N * bases(d)%g(ngd)%N * bases(a)%c(nga) &
                * bases(b)%c(ngb) * bases(c)%c(ngc) * bases(d)%c(ngd)
        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do 
        end do
        end do
        end do
        end do
end subroutine Build_Electron_Repulsion


real(dp) function Rntuv(n, tmax, umax, vmax, p, Px, Py, Pz, Ax, Ay, Az) result(out)
!Rntuv(n, t,u,v,p,P,A)Determine the helper integral Rntuv for the coulomb
!integral of order n, the t,u,v th Hermite polynomial with exponent p
!centered at [Px Py Pz] and charge centered at location [Ax Ay Az];
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n, tmax, umax, vmax
real(dp), intent(in) :: Px, Py, Pz, Ax, Ay, Az, p
real(dp) :: PA2, output
real(dp), dimension(n+tmax+umax+vmax+2, tmax+1, umax+1, vmax+1) :: R
integer :: nmax, t, u, v
integer :: i, IFLAG

R=0
nmax = n+ tmax + umax + vmax + 2
PA2 = (Px-Ax)**2.0D0 + (Py-Ay)**2.0D0 + (Pz-Az)**2.0D0

do i = 0, nmax-1
        output=Boys(i, p*PA2)

        R(i+1,1,1,1)= (-2*p)**(1.0D0*i)*Boys(i, p*PA2)

end do

do t=1, tmax
        if (t==1) then
                do i=1,nmax-1
                        R(i,2,1,1)=(Px - Ax)*R(i+1,1,1,1)
                end do
        else
                do i=1,nmax-1
                        R(i,t+1,1,1)=(t-1)*R(i+1,t-1,1,1)+ (Px-Ax)*R(i+1,t,1,1)
                end do
        end if
end do

do u = 1,umax

  if (u==1) then
                do i = 1,nmax-1
                        R(i,tmax+1,2,1)=(Py-Ay)*R(i+1,tmax+1,1,1)
                end do

        else
                do i = 1,nmax-1
                        R(i,tmax+1,u+1,1)=(u-1)*R(i+1,tmax+1,u-1,1) + (Py-Ay)*R(i+1,tmax+1,u,1)
                end do
        end if
end do

do v=1,vmax
        if (v==1) then
                do i = 1, nmax-1
                        R(i,tmax+1,umax+1,2)=(Pz-Az)*R(i+1,tmax+1,umax+1,1)
                end do
        else
                do i = 1, nmax-1
                        R(i,tmax+1,umax+1,v+1)=(v-1)*R(i+1,tmax+1,umax+1,v-1) + (Pz-Az)*R(i+1,tmax+1,umax+1,v)
                end do
        end if
end do


out = R(n+1,tmax+1,umax+1,vmax+1)
end function Rntuv

subroutine gprod_1D(x1, alpha1, lx1, x2, alpha2, lx2, Ex)
real(dp), intent(in) :: x1, alpha1, x2, alpha2
integer, intent(in) :: lx1, lx2
integer :: tmax, i, j ,t, qint
real(dp) :: p, q, midpoint, weighted_middle, KAB
real(dp), dimension(maxl), intent(inout) :: Ex
real(dp), dimension(maxl, maxl, 2*maxl) ::coefficients
coefficients=0.0D0


tmax=lx1 + lx2
Ex=0
p=alpha1 + alpha2
q=alpha1*alpha2/p
midpoint = x1 - x2
weighted_middle=(alpha1*x1 + alpha2*x2)/p

KAB= e**(-q*midpoint**2.0D0)
coefficients(1,1,1) = KAB

i=0
j=0
do while (i < lx1)

        do t= 0, i+j+1
                if (t==0) then
                        coefficients(i+2,j+1,t+1)=(weighted_middle - x1)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+1) + (t+1)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+2)

                else
                        coefficients(i+2,j+1,t+1)=1/(2*p)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t) + (weighted_middle-x1)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+1) + &
                                (t+1)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+2)

                end if
        end do
        i=i+1
end do

do while (j < lx2)
        do t=0, i+j+1
                if (t==0) then
                        coefficients(i+1,j+2,t+1) = (weighted_middle - x2)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+1) + (dble(t)+1.0d0)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+2)

                else

                        coefficients(i+1,j+2,t+1)=1/(2*p)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t) + (weighted_middle - x2)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+1) + &
                                (t+1)*coefficients(i+1,j+1,t+2)
                end if
        end do
j=j+1
end do
do qint=1, i+j+1
        Ex(qint) = coefficients(i+1,j+1,qint)
end do
end subroutine gprod_1D
```

Comment: Another frequent cause of the problem that inserting `print` statements 'fixes' (or causes) is mismatching routine dummy and actual arguments.  It's impossible to tell from what you've posted whether you have taken care to do this, or not.

Comment: Are your subroutines in a module? You should show how you are calling them (including definitions of all arguments).

Comment: Please double check that your code does not include unintended instances of locally saved variables. The fact that `integer x; x = 42` is not equivalent to `integer :: x = 42` but in fact `integer, save :: x = 42` surprises many new Fortraners who are familiar with the C/C++ family. The line `real(dp), dimension(2*maxl, 2*maxl, 2*maxl) :: R=0` may very well be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I went through my code and eliminated all initializations like you mentioned jlokimlin.  But I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: " What I'm really wondering is if you have any tips on tracking down where the error might be. " That has been mentioned many times, enable all checks, sanitizations, use valgrind, debugging prints, trace the program line-by line in a debugger...

Comment: Nevermind.  I was adding code into the block above to help address Vladimir F's concern, and then found an additional initialization of real(dp), dimension(nb,nb) :: R=0 in the build_electron_repulsion routine.  That routine only gets called one time in the program, so I don't understand how that would have caused these problems, but changing that made the errors go away.  Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: I by no means wanted to correct the writing of a native speaker, but the paragraph was very long and the sentences complicated. It is difficult to read.